# Convert list into dataframe python by converting list elements into rows and columns

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I currently have a list with 25 elements in (shape is 25,1).  This contains just the data items. I want to convert the list elements into a pandas DataFrame with 5 columns and 5 rows.  I have to colNames separately and just want to use the following method:

```
myList = ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,18,20,21,22,23,24,25])
df = pd.DataFrame(myList,columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'])
```

Obviously, the above code won't work as my list element and subsequent df shape are different.  Is there a simple way to split the list elements into rows after every 5th element?  Also, bear in mind that I haven't created the list as in the example above - I just want to be able to perform the second line once the list has been transformed into the appropriate shape.  I guess I could try converting the list to a numpy array first and then reshaping it this way, then converting to Pandas DataFrame, but just wanted to see if there was a quicker way.

Comment: Avoid using reserved keywords as variable names. list is reserved for the list type in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Take long list of items and reshape into dataframe "rows" - pandas python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42719765/take-long-list-of-items-and-reshape-into-dataframe-rows-pandas-python-3)

Comment: Perfect - I did try and find an answer before posting - but this answers it perfectly!  Thanks.

Comment: Closed as a duplicate, per the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Numpy works well here:

```
import numpy as np
myList = ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,18,20,21,22,23,24,25])
myList = np.asarray(myList).reshape(5,5)
print(myList)
```

will output

```
array([[ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8,  9, 10],
       [11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 18, 20],
       [21, 22, 23, 24, 25]])
```

Comment: Beat me to it !

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you all :-)

Comment: I'll accept the solution as soon as I'm able to.

Answer (score 1):

```
import math
import pandas as pd

l = ([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,18,20,21,22,23,24,25])
df=[l[5*i:5*i+5] for i in range(0,math.ceil(len(l)/5))]

df = pd.DataFrame(df,columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'])
print(df)
```

output:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
0     1     2     3     4     5
1     6     7     8     9    10
2    11    12    13    14    15
3    16    17    18    18    20
4    21    22    23    24    25
```

Answer (score 0):

### Just in case without `numpy`

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

ls = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,18,20,21,22,23,24,25]
size = 5

ls = [ls[i::size] for i in range(size)]

df = pd.DataFrame(ls,columns=['Col1', 'Col2', 'Col3', 'Col4', 'Col5'])
```

**Output**

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5
1       6       11      16      21
2       7       12      17      22
3       8       13      18      23
4       9       14      18      24
5       10      15      20      25
```